# How to Localize Standard Command Groups

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

When using the build in command groups with SwiftUI like `SidebarCommands()` or `ToolbarCommands()`, how can one localize the menu items as they are not translated by default.

I tried to add the English menu item strings to my `Localization.strings` and translated them, but this didn't work.

I don't want to replace them with my own custom commands as I would then need to implement the actions by myself.

```
@main
struct SwiftUIApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            SidebarCommands() // This is not localizable
            ToolbarCommands() // This is not localizable
            CommandGroup(after: CommandGroupPlacement.appInfo) {
                Button(action: viewModel.toggleSidebar) {
                    Text("Toggle Sidebar") // This is localizable
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide minimal reproducible example to demo which commands are not localized when others, yours in this case, are localized.

Comment: I updated my example to show how I could localize a custom command, but I would loose the functionality.